# Bootstrap 4 flexible grid not working in IE

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I'm using Bootstrap 4 to achieve a flexible grid. I'm running into an issue in IE 11 where flexbox isn't responding appropriately to a simple grid like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="col-sm-2 red">16.67%</td>
      <td class="col-sm-2 blue">16.67%</td>
      <td class="col-sm-3 green">25%</td>
      <td class="col-sm-1 yellow">8.33%</td>
      <td class="col-sm-1 orange">8.33%</td>
      <td class="col-sm-3 purple">25%</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nd7urfvw/) that works great in Chrome and Firefox. What can I do to remedy this in IE?

Comment: It's because you are using bootstrap classes inside a `table`, don't know why you would do that instead of using `divs` in this case... Any reason for the table particularly?

Comment: Removing the table and using divs displays the row as intended: https://imgur.com/a/uD9G1uv

Comment: @IvanS95 in my actual site, I am using this flexbox to display tabular data. Thus, using HTML tables. Why would this work in every browser besides IE?

Comment: there's some advice here about enabling flexbox properly for bootstrap4 - might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25385798/1777072

Comment: I imagine something to do with IE's html engine, the link above seems to be very helpful